# " 'Such' amount" or " 'such an' amount"?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Is there any difference between them!? If you **google** both: [1](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22such+amount%22) and [2](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=%22such+an+amount%22), the amount of retrieved results are very similar. I'd like to know if there's any (grammar) rule that makes it clear when to use *an* after *such*.

PS: I used *amount* only as a means of an illustrative example.

UPDATE (example using *such [an] amount of money*):

- "provisions shall be deemed **such an amount of money** or indebtedness as bears the same proportion"
- "on and after 2011, **such amount of money** as may be authorized by the Secretary of the Defense may be withheld temporarily..."

Comment: Ivan, can you give an example sentence where the meaning is ambiguous?

Comment: Can you give here a full sentence for both? Give variations where you see fit, but at list give us more context.

Comment: If your question is "If I can use a general "article usage" rule even for SUCH" why don't you change the title? For example: " 'Such' number " or " 'Such a number' " - referring to 'amount' you introduce an ambiguous element

Comment: @Carlo_R. Sorry but I don't understand your comment. Why is the word "amount" ambiguous where the term "number" isn't?

Comment: Such big ears, the better to hear you with /
Such big eyes, the better to see you with /
Such big teeth, the better to eat you with /
Little red riding hood, my dear

Comment: @Paola ... because 'amount' is a mass noun.

Comment: @MattЭллен I've updated the post with a simple example.

Comment: @Ivan: In your examples it's really a matter of personal preference whether you include the indefinite article or not, but most people probably *would*. Note that such constructions often invove the plural, where you can't have an article - it's always got to be **such amounts as may be deemed fit**.

Comment: @Carlo_R. This is exactly the point. By ensuring that "amount" is an ambiguous word, you mean there is no grammar rule to apply "an" after "such", i.e., it depends on the context (noun after the term such, in this case)?!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hence, there's no specific grammar rule, it will solely depend on my preference (based on the context, perhaps)?!

Comment: @Matt - yo, matt, have you heard - I have individuated exactly the point. Now you can answer.

Comment: @Ivan: There's no "rule" here - with words that can be either mass **or** count nouns (such as *amount* or *noise*) you have a free choice. If the word can only be a mass noun, such as *havoc*, you can't use the article (i.e. - we say *"He caused such havoc"*, not *"He caused such **a** havoc"*).

Comment: @FumbleFinger - this is a great answer. Why do not you post that; i will upvote

Comment: @Carlo_R: Since *number* can be both a mass and a count noun, it also allows the article to be present or not. Thus [such number as...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22such+number+as%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is just as valid as [such **a** number as...](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22such+a+number+as%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Hey y'all... look at [this comparison](http://bit.ly/JyaydF) (by Google NGram environment), and check out the trends on the use of *such an amount* vs. *such amount*. It seems very interesting. What do you think about that?

Comment: Are you sure you got that Ngram link right?  When I clicked, it compared "such **as** amount" with "such amount".  That was easy enough to fix, but now I'm wondering, which trends you are referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an interesting question!  Such thought-provoking remarks in the comments beneath the question!

Such comments make me wonder, what is the best way to answer such a query?  Maybe a few things need to be addressed first, such as:

- What is the meaning of *such*?
- How is it used in conversation and such?
- What is grammatical, and what sounds natural?

A good online dictionary, such as [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/such?suggested_from=Such), might help.  There, we can find such a great number of meanings and examples, that it will become readily apparent that such a question is not so easily answered.  English can be such a hard thing to fully grasp, particularly when dealing with such words – words that can be used in such a myriad of ways!  After all, many words, though but one word, can be used as *different* parts of speech: adjectives, adverbs, pronouns and such; *such* is one such word.

Really, Ivan, you should go visit such a [website](http://www.wordnik.com/words/such?suggested_from=Such), and behold the diverse ways such a simple word can be used.  Such a curious man is bound to learn something from such a great smattering of examples!

<sub>which is to say, there's no EASY way to tell when to use "such", and when to use "such a" - the word is simply too flexible to nail down in such a fashion...</sub>

Comment: such an answer!

Comment: such a such of such you have used, totally to say nothing. Hence -1

Comment: @Carlo_R. I guess @ J.R. used so many "such" to show how difficult is to properly apply the word "such". I don't think this is a dummy answer. It was a funny way to try to explain "such a" complex issue. by the way (just for fun...): "such a complex", or "such complex"?!... lol

Comment: @IvanMachado: It is as FumbleFingers says, it depends on the plurality of the noun following.  In this case it would either be *'such complex issues'* (with issues plural) or *'such a complex issue'* (singular)

Comment: @Jim I see, man... in this specific case, it was only a joke - see the "just for fun" mention in the comment. I've realized that using such with or without an article afterwards is not a matter of grammar rule, but "field practice" indeed. Thanks for the comment!