# 'Such' in place of a demonstrative pronoun. Such a configuration or such configuration?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar, scientific-language

I read some [explanations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198941/in-such-case-and-in-such-a-case) about the use of 'such' as a [determiner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/such-amount-or-such-an-amount), but I still could not figure this out. If, in scientific/formal writing, I want to use 'such' instead of 'this' to specify a previously mentioned noun, do I need the article a? E.g.:

> By adding a correct constant voltage on one of the plates, the AC goes to zero. *In such configuration*, the DC-voltage is the same as the original potential difference between the materials.

Which one would be correct: such **a** configuration or such configuration?

Comment: _Such a_ configuration.

Comment: "Such configuration" could be used when the act of "configuration" it the topic, but not in the above example.